# is it possible to directly mount a subdirectory of a smb path?

Tags: mount, smb

I am new to osx but am very experienced with Linux and Windows. I need to mount a subdirectory of a shared drive so the user can access it without being confused by seeing higher levels in the smb path.

I've read around and it appears that Lion only mounts the root of a smb share. I hope this is incorrect so am asking for some tips.

Ideally I would mount smb://path/to/the/directory and this would appear for the user to access. The stuff above the directory would not appear.

Thanks.

Comment: I have found this which I will try http://superuser.com/questions/390813/mount-a-smb-shares-subfolder-as-a-drive-in-os-x-lion but I am not sure how to make it persistent (there appears to be no /etc/fstab) and I am not sure how it will appear to user in her finder.

Comment: for some reason when I do this "mount_smbfs -N smb://myserver/myshare /Volumes/myshare" I get "mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Broken pipe". It works fine through the finder. I think I'll just do that for now.